# How to change the color of button with another button in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 button and i want with one of the button change the background color of the other button.

For example : when i click button 1 , then button 2 and 3 and 4 change their color to black and red and yellow

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUbbc.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are the images linked to what should the code look like in your files.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Functions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button1">button1</button>
    <button class="button2">button2</button>
    <button class="button3">button3</button>
    <button class="button4">button4</button>

    <script src="new.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**new.js**

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('.button1')
const button2 = document.querySelector('.button2')
const button3 = document.querySelector('.button3')
const button4 = document.querySelector('.button4')

function buttonColor() {
    button2.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    button2.style.color = 'white';
    button3.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    button4.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

button1.addEventListener('click', buttonColor)
```

Comment: worked , thank you so much. is there also anyway without class ?  i mean with getelementbyid

Comment: Please don't paste images as answers to questions. You should update the answer with working code in a snippet, or at least just some code. Imgur might become available and so this answer will be useless.

Comment: I was just helping to make sure that he/she got the answer. I was trying to give answer through writing code, but it was not helping the one with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button1Element.onclick = function () => {
  Button2el.style.backgroundColor = "YourcolorCode" ;
  Button3el.style.backgroundColor = "YourcolorCode" ;
  Button4el.style.backgroundColor = "YourcolorCode" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do this, I am selecting the buttons with their class name.

```
const button1 = document.querySelector('.button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('.button2');
const button3 = document.querySelector('.button3');
const button4 = document.querySelector('.button4');
```

Now you have all the buttons stored in variables. After this I will define a function and here I will use all the button stored in the constants and I will then style each of the button with different background color. But also make sure to add color white in the button2 where the color of background is black.

```
function buttonColor() {
          button2.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
          button2.style.color = 'white';
          button3.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          button4.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';    
       }

button1.addEventListener('click' , buttonColor);
```

Comment: the code does not work

Comment: Share your html and javaScript files with me. I will tell you how it is done.

Comment: i just added a photo, take a look

Comment: First of all remove the function btnClick.

Comment: Then see you have given the id to the buttons. change the id="button1" to class="button1" because in javascript we have selected the buttons who have classes.

Comment: Let me send you a file.

Comment: im gonna remove , ok send the file

Answer (score 0):

If you add [data ids to the buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), use CSS classes, and add the colors to an array, you can iterate over the buttons when a button has been clicked, and reapply the classes to each button that hasn't been clicked.

```js
const colors = ['black', 'red', 'yellow']

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button =>  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false));

function handleClick() {

  // Get the id of the button
  const id = Number(this.dataset.id) - 1;

  // `color` maintains the index of
  // the colors in the array 
  let color = 0;

  // Remove all classes from the clicked button
  this.className = '';

  // Iterate over the buttons
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

    // If the current index doesn't match the button id
    // add the color from the array at the current `color`
    // and then increment `color`
    if (i !== id) {
      buttons[i].className = colors[color];
      ++color;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.black { background-color: black; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<button data-id="1">One</button>
<button data-id="2">Two</button>
<button data-id="3">Three</button>
<button data-id="4">Four</button>
```